# Constexpr expand constructor parameter pack into member array (C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, template-argument-deduction

I want to expand a pack of variadic parameters into a struct member in C++11. My approach is the following:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct cxpr_struct
{
    constexpr cxpr_struct(Ts... Args) : t_(Args...) {}
    std::array<int, sizeof...(Ts)> t_;
};

int main()
{
    cxpr_struct(10, 20, 30);
}
```

However, this yields the following error:

```
<source>:208:16: error: missing template arguments before '(' token
  208 |     cxpr_struct(10, 20, 30);
      |
```

I know that my code has flaws. E.g. the type of array is not determined from Ts (how can I do that?). But how would I do this the proper way? Is template argument deduction really not possible for the compiler?

EDIT: I have to use C++11

Comment: What type is the array supposed to have? Do you want to require all the arguments to be the same type?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you using an old compiler?

Comment: @ecatmur: Sorry, I forgot to specify I need to use C++11 :)

Comment: @user17732522 yes all arguments are supposed be of the same type.

Comment: @ecatmur As written it will only work in C++20. The question was already tagged C++11.

Comment: Brain pain to think more than 10 years back... compiler update? No chance?

Comment: There is no CTAD in c++11. You need a factory function or specify the type explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to c++11, you have to use something like that:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct cxpr_struct
{
    constexpr cxpr_struct(Ts... args) : t_{args...} {}
    std::array<int, sizeof...(Ts)> t_;
};

template<typename... Ts>
cxpr_struct<Ts...> build(Ts...args){
    return cxpr_struct<Ts...>(args...);
}

int main()
{
    auto obj = build(10, 20, 30);
}
```

or better:

```
template <unsigned Size>
struct cxpr_struct
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    constexpr cxpr_struct(Ts... args) : t_{args...} {}
    std::array<int, Size> t_;
};

template<typename... Ts>
cxpr_struct<sizeof...(Ts)> build(Ts...args){
    return cxpr_struct<sizeof...(Ts)>(args...);
}

int main()
{
    auto obj = build(10, 20, 30);
}
```